# What do you call the bigger compartment of a refrigerator that doesn't freeze?

Tags: single-word-requests

1. Is the answer "chiller"?
2. If not, what's correct term?

Please see green arrow below. I read [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/The-refrigerator-is-the-whole-unit-and-we-call-the-freezer-the-freezer-but-what-do-we-call-the-side-that-doesn-t-freeze-if-we-were-specific).

[image]

Comment: The fridge compartment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Britain, we have freezers, and we have refrigerators (fridges), and they can be different appliances. A freezer is for keeping food frozen for longer periods, and a refrigerator is for keeping food cool for shorter periods.  The appliance in the picture combines both and would be called a 'fridge-freezer'.

The parts are:

At the top the freezer

Beneath that, the fridge or refrigerator.

Some appliances just called 'refrigerators' have a small compartment called an 'ice-box' or 'freezer compartment' which can be used to keep a small amount of frozen food for a short time. A refrigerator without any freezer compartment at all is called a 'larder refrigerator' or 'larder fridge'.

Comment: I believe that in the US, the whole thing is likely called simply a 'refrigerator'.